# I have an ignored folder but it is still showing whenever I do 'git status' as untracked files

Tags: node.js, git

This is my folder structure, really simple:

```
root-folder
|-- node_modules
|-- public
|-- .gitignore
|-- app.js
|-- package.json
```

Initially I commited the node_modules folder but I later added it to the .gitignore and is no longer present on my repo, but everytime I run `git status` this message is appearing as if the folder was not on the .gitignore:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

node_modules/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I already did a `git rm -r --cached node_modules` but seems to do nothing.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: Corrected node-modules to node_modules, but not the real issue, only a typo.

Comment: It appears that `node_modules/` is appearing under your untracked file list.  Does this folder still exist locally on your machine?  I don't see anything wrong here, per se, so long as `node_modules/` does not start showing up in your index again.

Comment: node_modules is not node-modules.

Comment: try `git rm -r --cached .`

Comment: @Fred is right, but that was a typo only, not the real issue. Correcting the typo now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking a lot around I found the issue by going to GitHub and looking at the .gitignore file, it was having a really weird character at the beginning of `node_modules/`, but for some reason it was not appearing on Sublime Text.

Now it is correctly ignoring the folder.